# Writing custom Api methods to access salesforce data in IOs salesforce Mobile app.

Tags: soql, salesforce1-app, metadata-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I want to write some Custom methods to access the salesforce data in IOS mobile App. I am new with salesforce Mobile. I have Installed Salesforce IOS SDK , But I am not aware that how should I write the custom methods. 
can someone help me out on this.Please answer with all the requirements and technologies that I can use to achieve this. Any tutorial is also appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

There is very good tutorials available on TrailHead which you can use here
[Native iOS](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/mobile_sdk_native_ios)

And there are many others for Complete [Mobile SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/trail/mobile_sdk_intro). So you can check them and they will surely help you.

and also you can do something like can use the `webservice` keyword in Apex Code to generate a file that can export a WSDL, then use that in `IOS`, or you can use `@RestResource` on a class, and then call that method